# взять из элемента все до тега br

Tags: jquery

Например есть код

```
<div>  какой-то текст <br><span>какой-то текст 2</span></div>
```

мне надо достать только "какой-то текст". Если использовать .text(), то соответсвенно берется все из элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log($("div").html().split("<br>")[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>  какой-то текст <br><span>какой-то текст 2</span></div>
```